# OpenStack - assign security group to existing instance

Tags: openstack

I want to assign a security group to an existing instance. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you can:

In the Horizon web interface provided that you have a pretty recent version of Horizon, i.e. >= Grizzly: [Change security group](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/2295/change-security-group/):

> It's possible to change the security groups on the fly using Horizon,
>   if you're using the latest release Grizzly. Click on the "More" button
>   for the instance you want to update and you should see an "Edit
>   Security Groups" option.
>
> In the CLI, use nova help [add-secgroup](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/novaclient_commands.html)
>
> The code for this was added a year ago so I believe this should be
>   available in Folsom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new security group called new.

Get the id of your image (`<image-id>`)

```
select id from security_groups where name = 'new' ;
update security_group_instance_association set security_group_id=<security-group-id> where instance_id=<image-id> ;
```

Comment: Where are we supposed to run this query?